# En Angular mi app no se actualiza, solo aparece "app is running"

Tags: angular

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de Angular 8, haciendo una app con un componente (Dado se llama el componente), pero el contenido de la componente no se ve en el navegador, solo me aparece "app is running".
¿Dónde puede estar la falla?

Estos son los archivos de AppComponent:

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform- 
 browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DadoComponent } from './dado/dado.component';


@NgModule({
 declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  DadoComponent
 ],
 imports: [
  BrowserModule
 ],
 providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html:

```
  <div style="text-align:center">
   <app-dado></app-dado>
   <app-dado></app-dado>
   <app-dado></app-dado>  
  </div>
```

Y estos son los archivos de DadoComponent:

dado.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-dado',
 templateUrl: './dado.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dado.component.css']
})

export class DadoComponent implements OnInit {
   valor: number;
   constructor() { }

   ngOnInit() {
    this.valor = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
   }

 }
```

dado.component.html:

```
<div class="forma">
  {{valor}}
</div>
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Podrias adjuntar tu index.html?

Comment: Index.html: `<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Proyecto004</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: gracias, podrías adjuntar el código de app.component.ts también?